# How to show select box items in multiple section in Grails

Tags: javascript, html, grails, select, drop-down-menu

I am using Grails 2.1.1. I have a many select box that contains so much data. Now I want to show 10 items in each display of select. And there should be next previous icon to navigate at bottom of select box.

I have searched for it but found no solution. Is it possible to do it in Grails?

Comment: An HTML select doesn't have the capability of adding a button. This really should be an HTML/JavaScript question. The Grails part is just adding a controller method to return the requested range of data.

Comment: You may ratherthan select box use a drop down that will look like select box  and yes it can have buttons inside it :)

Comment: @VinayPrajapati, any link or source code would have help me a lot